# Why wouldn't gcc compile this trivial code that calls free() function?

Tags: c++, gcc, memory-management

I tried the following code on both codepad.org and [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/ser2G):

```
char* ptr = new char;
free( ptr );
```

Yes, I know it's undefined behavior, but I want to compile it and run it to see what happens.

Visual C++ 10 compiles it, but gcc which is used on the abovementioned sites says

> error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token

Why wouldn't this code compile with gcc and how could I make it compile?

Comment: [Looks ok to me](http://ideone.com/4dylS).

Comment: You should have posted the links as well. After all, they're all online!

Comment: @Nawaz: Added link to ideone.com

Comment: What a shame. I forgot to put that code into `main()`.

Comment: Yeap, I forgot to put that code into `main()`. Should stop coding for this week.

Comment: Even `main()` is not going to help if you write `free(ptr)` at the namespace scope. Read my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This code](http://ideone.com/X4vZa) indeed will not compile. You have to add `main()` call also.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* ptr = new char;
    free( ptr );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to call `free()` from `main()` in order to compile. `free()` can be called from namespace scope as well. This is trick, for which see my solution.

Comment: Yes, but I don't think OP was going to apply this trick, he just forgot to write `main()`

Answer (score 5):

Here is your code (from [your link](http://ideone.com/ser2G)):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

char* ptr = new char;
free( ptr );
```

`free()` is a function, and at the namespace scope,you cannot write function-call-statement.

At namespace scope, you can only *declare* and *define* variables, and types. You can call a function in **the initialization** of a variable, however. So this is okay:

```
char* ptr = new char; //Note new is a function call!
```

But  this is NOT okay:

```
free(ptr);
```

If you want to do that, then here is one trick:

```
const int ignore = (free(ptr), 0); //at namespace scope!
```

This is okay. Demo : http://ideone.com/8yymM

Answer (score 2):

You can only call a function without a visible declaration in C. In C++ it is an error that must be diagnosed at compile time, it's not *undefined behavior*.

To call `free` you must include the `stdlib.h` header.

Comment: I actually did that http://ideone.com/ser2G - it doesn't help.

Comment: I've assumed that your posted code is in a function body? I can't think of anything else that would cause a compile error. My version of gcc gives "error: 'free' was not declared in this scope" which is a more helpful error message.

Answer (score 2):

The proper code should be this one:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char* ptr = new char;
   free( ptr );
}
```

The error depends on the fact that free(ptr) at global scope is not seen as a function call, but as a declaration of an object of `class free` :-o  .

By the way, consider also that the opposite of `ptr = new char` is not `free(ptr)`, but `delete ptr`. (free is the opposite of `malloc`. `new` calls `malloc`, but does a bit more. As `delete` calls `free` but does something more).

Answer (score 1):

Did you include `<stdlib.h>`? It could be that the compiler doesn't recognize `free`

Answer (score 0):

Because it's c++, so you need to use g++ instead of gcc.

Comment: I can't control that - I only have a "language" switch on those sites. I select the language and the site select the compiler executable. I can't believe they do that wrong - they would be unusable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I missed where you said you were using the online compilers.  I just thought "Ah! I've made that stupid mistake myself before!" Hah.